# Populating child attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table which contains `<td>`'s with `data-label` attributes.
Using jQuery I would like to populate the child `input` tag `placeholder` tag.

**HTML**:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-label="Some placeholder text goes here"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-label="Some placeholder text goes here"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-label="Some placeholder text goes here"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**:

```
$('td[data-label]').children('input').attr('placeholder', $(this).data('label'));
```

Using this code above, the placeholders are not set, could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `.data()` from the `td`, as your input doesn't have a `data-label attr`. So you can use `.closest('td')` to refer `td's` data

```
$('td[data-label] input').attr('placeholder',function(){
  return $(this).closest('td').data('label');
});
```

Check the **below snippet:**

```js
$('td[data-label] input').attr('placeholder', function() {
  return $(this).closest('td').data('label');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-label="Some placeholder text goes here">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-label="Some placeholder text goes here">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-label="Some placeholder text goes here">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `this` does not refer to what you are expecting.

try this :

```js
$('td[data-label]').each(function() {
  $(this).children('input').attr('placeholder', $(this).data('label'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-label="Some placeholder text goes here"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-label="Some placeholder text goes here"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-label="Some placeholder text goes here"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td[data-label]').each(function(td){
    $td = $(td);
    label = $td.data('label');

    $td.find('input').prop('placeholder', label);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're in the input in your loop but you want to set the value of the placeholder on the parent's data label attribute. You also want to use a function to return a value in your callback:

```
$('td[data-label]').children('input').attr('placeholder', function() {
  return $(this).parent().data('label')
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/npsyb59z/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
//loop through each row of the table 
    $("tr").each(function() {
//get the value of the data-label attribute
        var placeholderText = $(this).find("td").attr("data-label");
//assign the data-label value captured above to teh placeholder property of the input
        $(this).find("input").attr("placeholder", placceholderText );
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, please you need to alter your answer with a little description about what your code does. Thank you.